# What how does the Ok(value) pattern work in for loops?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, semantics

I am not understanding how the following pattern will work:

```rust
for Ok(value) in do_thing_get_results(){
    use_thing(value)
}
```

Will the loop ignore `Err` results? Will it simply `.unwrap()` them and panic? Does it have another clause for handling `Err` values, to save me from writing a `match`?

Comment: Where was this code seen?

Comment: You probably meant `while let Ok(value) = ...`. The answer is that the loop will stop on the first `Err` without giving you a chance to report the error. It is probably not what you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to notice about this piece of code.

First, `for` loops can contain patterns. From [the reference, syntax of `for` loops](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops):

> <sup>**Syntax**</sup>
> *IteratorLoopExpression* :
>   `for` *[Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html)* `in` *[Expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html)<sub>except struct expression</sub>* *[BlockExpression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html)*

This is the same as `let` statements, that can have patterns in their bindings, or function arguments. E.g. `let _ = ...;` (`_` is the [wildcard pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#wildcard-pattern)) or `fn f(Struct(v): Struct) {}` (where `struct Struct(v);`).

However, as opposed to patterns in `match` or `if let`, patterns in these positions are required to be [irrefutable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#refutability). That means that pattern match should *always* succeed.

The pattern `Ok(v)` usually belongs to the enum `Result<T, E>`, where `Ok` is one of the variants. This means it is a *refutable* pattern, meaning it is forbidden for use in `for` loops. So this code should be a compile time error.

Unless...

There are two ways this code will work:

The first is the `Ok` name being shadowed by your own name. For example,

```rust
pub struct Ok<T>(pub T);

fn foo(v: Vec<Ok<i32>>) {
    for Ok(v /* : i32 */) in v { /* ... */ }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ff83b6f27d1019cc31bfcb03f3580db).

The second is if `Result` had one variant only. Matching against one-variant enum *is* irrefutable.

But `Result` has two variants!

There is a special (unstable) type, [the never type, denoted `!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.never.html), that means "can not exist". If we fill the `Err` variant with `!` (which is possibly since `Result` is generic over the error type)...

```rust
enum Result<T, !> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(!),
}
```

...we get an enum that is practically the same as:

```rust
enum Result<T> {
    Ok(T),
}
```

That is, one-variant enum, since the `Err` case can never exist.

There is an unstable feature, named `exhaustive_patterns`, that allows us to treat such cases as irrefutable:

```rust
#![feature(never_type, exhaustive_patterns)]

fn foo(v: Vec<Result<i32, !>>) {
    for Ok(v /* : i32 */) in v { /* ... */ }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e9b3d5009e93d9a3750ff1970aad47c).

(Note: this applies not only to the never type, but also to any other infallible type, such as [`std::convert::Infallible`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't compile at all. Rust doesn't allow you to use [refutable patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html) in a `for` loop binding.

There are multiple ways you can go over the `Ok` variants if that's what you want. One is to use an `if let` statement *inside* the loop. Example:

```
let res_values = vec![
    Ok(11),
    Ok(22),
    Err(MyError::new("Foo")),
    Ok(33),
];
for r in res_values {
    if let Ok(v) = r {
        println!("An Ok value: {}", v);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
An Ok value: 11
An Ok value: 22
An Ok value: 33
```

As can be seen, in that example we simply skipped the `Err`s.
However, if you want to handle the `Ok` variants *until* you come across an `Err` and if that happens, to simply return the error to the caller of your function, you can do something like this:

```
fn do_stuff() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    let res_values = vec![
        Ok(11),
        Ok(22),
        Err(MyError::new("Foo")),
        Ok(33),
    ];
    for r in res_values {
        println!("An Ok value: {}", r?);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Output:

```
An Ok value: 11
An Ok value: 22
```

Answer (score 2):

A proper MCVE give:

```rust
fn the_answer() -> Result<u32, ()> {
    Ok(42)
}

fn main() {
    for Ok(foo) in Some(the_answer()) {
        println!("{}", foo);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in `for` loop binding: `Err(_)` not covered
   --> src/main.rs:6:9
    |
6   |     for Ok(foo) in Some(the_answer()) {
    |         ^^^^^^^ pattern `Err(_)` not covered
    |
    = note: the matched value is of type `Result<u32, ()>`
```

> Patterns used to bind names must be irrefutable, that is, they must guarantee that a name will be extracted in all cases.
> If you encounter this error you probably need to use a match or if let to deal  with the possibility of failure
>
> [E0005](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0005)